# How to pass a lambda in place a reference to a functtor

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function template that takes an argument by reference

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T& arg)
{
  ...
}
```

I want to call it passing a lambda expression, e.g.

```
Foo([](SomeType& nd) {nd.dosomething();  })
```

This does not compile (no problem though when Foo is modified to take the argument by value). What should I do to be able to pass lambda in place of a reference to a functor?

Answer (score 3):

A lambda expression is a prvalue, and won't bind to an lvalue reference.

If you change `Foo` to take a forwarding reference, it will be able to accept both lvalues and rvalues:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T&& arg);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accept lvalues or rvalues, then you need to instead use a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).  That would turn your function into

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T&& arg) // not an rvalue reference, but a forwarding reference
{
    ...
}
```